# Video encoding in real time through node js?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

Do Anyone know realtime encode video in node with ffmpeg ? I know transloadit was done well on this. Any idea ?

https://transloadit.com/blog/2010/12/realtime-encoding-over-150x-faster

Answer (score 6):

Co-founder at [Transloadit](https://transloadit.com) here : ) We used pipes. Node.js allows us to see the data as it is still being uploaded (we used our [node-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) module). FFmpeg allows using stdin for input via `ffmpeg -i -`. So you can pipe uploaded bytes into that spawned child_process's stdin, and that's that : )

Off-topic, we later deprecated the feature. It turned out the market for it was less interested than we had imagined, and it sadly introduced enough operational headaches that we said goodbye to this, by us, beloved feature.

Answer (score 3):

Use Fluent FFMpeg. A tremendous module that can transcode on the fly:

https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg